# Error #sql-890_730 when creating constraint in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key

This is my `t_complaint`

```
    CREATE TABLE `t_complaint` (
  `idcomplaint` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tglterima` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pengirim` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kontak` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jenis` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uraian` text,
  `uniqueid` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `responder` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tgljawab` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `jawaban` text,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tglclose` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `createddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifieddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedby` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and this is `t_complaint_detail`:

```
    CREATE TABLE `t_complaint_detail` (
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uniqueid` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploader` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_uploader` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_upload` text,
  `original_name` text,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- t_complaint.idcomplaint is a primary key with Auto Increment attribute
- t_complaint_detail.no is a primary key with Auto Increment attribute
- I'd like to connected these table via `uniqueid`
- I've tried `ALTER TABLE t_complaint_detail ADD CONSTRAINT fk_unique FOREIGN KEY ('uniqueid') REFERENCES t_complaint('uniqueid')`
- The query above gives error. The error is `#1005 - Can't create table`bsm`.`#sql-890_730`(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)`
- `bsm` in the error is my database (my database is bsm)

Comment: `uniqueid` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,` replace the varchar with int and check

Comment: but, its value is string/text.

Comment: `uniqueid` is Foreign key here ? right?

Comment: yes. but i want these table connected via uniqueid

Comment: so, it's like connecting a foreign key in both table. is it possible. uniqueid in table complaint is unique (never has same value). but I assigned idcomplaint as the primary key since it has auto increment attribute

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key should must be a primary key in parent table. The question is, why you are adding a redundant 'uniqueId' in both the table? You can simply define a foreign key constraint like this :

t_complaint_detail ADD CONSTRAINT fk_unique FOREIGN KEY ('idcomplaint') REFERENCES t_complaint('idcomplaint').

It should work.

Comment: idcomplaint and no has no connection. They both act as primary key. But may have different value

Comment: It doesn't have to be on primary key and you would have to remove quotes around column name or replace them with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Error came like this

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Because you need to create `primary key` in table.you can add primary key
like this

```
alter table t_complaint_detail modify uniqueid varchar(20) not null;
```

and

```
alter table t_complaint_detail modify uniqueid varchar(20) not null;
```

after it will be works

```
ALTER TABLE t_complaint_detail ADD CONSTRAINT fk_unique FOREIGN KEY (uniqueid) REFERENCES t_complaint(uniqueid);
```

[please read here for more reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) that will be help

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me : 
Try this :

```
ALTER TABLE t_complaint ADD CONSTRAINT t_complaint_detail 
FOREIGN KEY ( uniqueid ) REFERENCES t_complaint( uniqueid )
```

Reference here : 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: It works because you removed the single quotes around uniqueid.